# Recovering GitLab repos from the server-side directories

Tags: git, ubuntu, gitlab, gitlab-ee

I had GitLab-CE running on an Ubuntu 16 VPS, but due to some nginx issues and just problems more generally, I ended up unable to log into GitLab on my server. Since I had to wipe the server anyway, I figured I'd just back up the `/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/` folder and hope for the best as far as recovering those with a new GitLab install later.

It's later. I now have GitLab-EE installed, the Omnibus version, on Ubuntu 18.04. I moved the folders from `/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/username/` from the backup to the new install. These are folders, named `reponame.git` and `reponame.wiki.git` for each one. I've got file permissions set correctly as well.

The only things that are clearly different is:

1. the user `git` belongs to the group `git` on the new repo made on the new server, but the old ones have group `root` with user `git`
2. When doing `ls -al`, the newly-created repo  has the following for hooks

`hooks -> /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/hooks/`

while the old has `hooks.old.1528595819/` which only had a readme file about hooks, but nothing helpful.

What are my chances of recovering these in the new GitLab installation? I can't just make `hooks` be a symlink to `/opt/gitlab/.../hooks/` for all of these and change the group of the owner, since that's not doing anything to get these to show up on the web interface.

What is my best option here?

Comment: `but I don't want to risk making anything worse with my current GitLab install` but you have reliable backup, or not? if you do, then why this bothers you? You break things more, then you restore and try again.

Comment: I have a backup of the repos. I have a snapshot of the Linode. But from experience I know that it's not always as easy as just restoring the snapshot and trying again. I've had snapshots restore with some things broken compared to how they were when it was taken. So, I'd rather just get the actual answer if someone knows it. If not, then I'll absolutely tinker my little heart out and see what's what.

Comment: More importantly, it's a lot of time lost if i do end up reverting to the snapshot. I'd rather not waste that time if I don't have to.

Comment: but still the question remains: why you even work on original data? why not restore on new instance and play there?

Comment: I don't have a bunch of extra VPS instances sitting around to do this on. It's a fairly straightforward question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've worked out a solution which is more time consuming than I'd like but it definitely got me all my files back. Here's what I did, in case it's helpful for someone else down the road. Lots of times stuff gets abandoned without answers, and if you're just trying to get your files back, this might do it for you.

1. Copied the folders (named [repo name].git) to a folder on a computer that isn't the server. Put each in its own containing folder. So for example `sample.git` gets put in a folder called `sample`.
2. Go to that directory in the terminal
3. Re-initialise the repo with `git init`
4. Restore the files locally with `git reset --hard HEAD`
5. Set the remote server as a new branch for that repo and commit. Now the files are showing up on the remote GitLab server as accessible.

The `git init` step was just a guess, but it's exactly what was needed.

I'd still love to hear if there's a quicker way to batch-renew repos all on the server, but in lieu of that, this works.

Comment: I came across your answer whilst looking for a solution to a similar problem. Unfortunately it didn't work for me; I ended up with a blank repo. However, having found your answer I was then inspired to look a bit further, and found this page: https://forum.gitlab.com/t/where-are-repo-files-stored/14892/3, with an answer from a user called Yama saying that the <long number>.git directories were in fact just bare repositories. And sure enough, copying that directory over to a PC and trying git on it, and I can read the log. So thank you for your answer, and I hope this comment helps others!

Comment: This worked for me, though I'll say that I needed to rename that "sample.git" directory to just ".git" once it was inside of the blank directory (before executing git init) :)